# Dispaly Category and SubCategory in Hierarchy in DropDownList

Tags: .net, sql-server, drop-down-menu, asp.net-4.0

I have to display the Category and SubCategory in the `dropdownlist` in hierarchy, like as follows:

```
cat1
    --cat11
           ----cat111
           ----cat112
           ----cat113
    --cat12
          ----cat121
          ----cat122
          ----cat123
cat2
     --cat21
           ----cat211
           ----cat212
           ----cat213
     --cat22
          ----cat221
          ----cat222
          ----cat223
```

I have to display it from SqlServer database, in which when the new category and subcategory is created it will reflect in the dropdown also.
I need it very much.
Please response soon.
Thanks in advance.
hariom.

Answer (score 1):

You may follow these steps -
Query both the categories and sub-categories in a single query like -

```
SELECT '-   '+SubCatName AS NameField,SubCatId AS ValueField,CatId FROM SubCat
UNION
SELECT CatName,0,CatId FROM Cat
ORDER BY CatId,SubCatId
```

Disable cat values -

```
foreach (ListItem item in drpDistricts.Items)
{
     if (item.Value.ToString() == "0")
     {
       item.Attributes.Add("Style", "color:maroon");
       item.Attributes.Add("Disabled", "true");
     }
}
```

if you like to read a complete article then see this post on my blog
http://suvendugiri.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/asp-net-dropdownlist-containing-category-sub-category-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a datareader to populate the dropdownlist. This will loop through the categories. You then do a seperate query on each category to get the subcategories, and then create the items. Sorry can't do example code right now! Perhaps the community can help?